# How do you set the save directory of Cobertura saveGlobalProjectData?

Tags: java, file, path, save, cobertura

While sifting through a slew of Stackoverflow topics for this all I have found is how to call saveGlobalProjectData using reflection:

```
String methodName = "saveGlobalProjectData";
Class saveClass = Class.forName(className);
java.lang.reflect.Method saveMethod = saveClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, new Class[0]);
saveMethod.invoke(null, new Object[0]);
logger.debug("Saved coverage data");
```

The problem I was having was this was saving the data to the working directory. In my case that is the ear file we deploy. This fails in fun ways.

If you are looking to change the directory this code saves to you must change the system property

```
net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile
```

Again in my case, this means editing the spc-jboss.conf.1 file with the following line:

```
-Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=/tmp/cobertura/cobertura_integration.ser
```

You'll notice you also can rename the file too! Added bonus!

One caution though is that I found this variable was run by cobertura early in the startup of the server. The cobertura code that gets this variable caches the result (the current working directory, see below) and will not overwrite it. This means you CAN NOT set this in code you run and expect the file location or name to change. It has to be done in server configuration.

Cobertura code (form different .java files but combined here):

```
public static File getDefaultDataFile() {
    // return cached defaultFile
    if (defaultFile != null) {
        return defaultFile;
    }

    // load and cache datafile configuration
    ConfigurationUtil config = new ConfigurationUtil();
    defaultFile = new File(config.getDatafile());

    return defaultFile;
}
public String getDatafile() {
    return getProperty("net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile",
            "cobertura.ser");
}
```

Hope this solution helps for all the people who want to use the reflection call and save the file to a specific directory with a specific name.

Comment: Couple comments: 1) the first code snippet is missing the value/declaration for "className". That's kind of important. 2) the etiquette/recommended way for posting a solution is to phrase the question first, then post an answer it yourself. That way, people looking for a problem can better find your question and people can contribute alternative answers too, or more updated versions in the future.